# Relationship between Productivity and Yield

Tags: reaction-control

I am trying to formulate an optimization problem. Can you help me understand the definition of productivity and yield? Why is there a trade-off between them during the reaction?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your application and the specifics, to keep it simple. . .

- Yield: The `amount of product` obtained in a chemical reaction
- Productivity: The `rate of speed a product can be obtained` in a chemical reaction

For the compromise, as vague example, perhaps the more of the product you want to yield, the more time it may take thus a longer productivity you'll have.